# Coefficients are all zero for lasso regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, lasso

I am implementing regression techniques to predict a continuous output. I have trained a model using lasso regression.

For some reason, the coefficients become all zero. I don't know why this is the case and I cannot find a solution to this. Can someone help please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more information about exactly what you did for anyone to provide a sensible answer.

Comment: Does this help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179109/why-are-all-lasso-coefficients-in-model-0-0?rq=1

Comment: RoyT provides the answer.